# The generator polynomial of cyclic code

Tags: coding-theory, linear-algebra

Let $q$ be a power of prime number $p$ and let $F_{q^2}$ be a finite field of order $q^2$.
Suppose that "-" be a conjugation operation that is defined as follow:

$-:F_{q^2} ‎\longrightarrow‎ ‎F_{q^2}$

$x ‎\longmapsto‎ x^q$

Let $C$ be a cyclic code of length n over $F_{q^2}$ with the generator polynomial $g(x)$ and let $\bar{C}=\lbrace \bar{c} : c \in C \rbrace$ be the conjugate code of $C$.

It is obvious that $\bar{C}$ is also a cyclic code.

Is it possible to determine the generator polynomial of $\bar{C}$ from $g(x)$?

Comment: The obvious choice works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator polynomial of $\bar{C}$ is $‎\overline{g(x)}‎$. Because the conjugation operation is distributive over summation and multiplication.